Using functional derivatives and Euler-Lagrange to obtain wave equation in 3d elastic media
I'm trying to solve exercise (1.5) from Lancaster and Blundell's Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur wherein we consider a 3D elastic material whose potential energy is given by
$$ V = \frac{\mathcal{T}}{2} \int d^3x \left( \nabla \psi \right)^2 $$ and kinetic energy is given by
$$ T = \frac{\rho}{2} \int d^3x \left( \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \right)^2 .$$ We want to use these and the principle of stationary action to obtain the wave equation.
In this case, the lagrangian is simply $L = T - V$ and the principle of stationary action is encoded by
$$ \frac{\delta L}{\delta \psi} = 0 = \frac{\delta T}{\delta \psi} - \frac{\delta V}{\delta \psi}  $$
I'm having trouble actually evaluating these functional derivatives.

Derivative of $V$:

$$ \frac{\delta V}{\delta \psi} = \frac{\mathcal{T}}{2} \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon} \left[ \int d^3 \left( \nabla (\psi + \epsilon \delta^3(r-r') \right)^2 - \int d^3 \left( \nabla \psi \right)^2 \right] \\ = \frac{\mathcal{T}}{2} \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon} \left[ \int d^3 \left( \nabla (\psi + \epsilon \delta^3(r-r') \right)^2 - \int d^3 \left( \nabla \psi \right)^2 \right] $$
After using linearity to write
$$ (\nabla(\psi + \epsilon \delta^3(r-r'))^2 = (\nabla(\psi) + \nabla(\epsilon \delta^3(r-r'))^2 \approx \nabla(\psi) + 2\epsilon\nabla \delta^3(r-r') $$
I'm not sure how to deal with the vector calculus related to the dirac-delta function. I'd appreciate any tips/references to books where I can learn about the dirac-delta distribution and how to deal with it in these vector calculus contexts. Thank you!
